# Fetching mac address of devices connected to remote subnet using python / pysnmp

Tags: python, snmp, subnet, pysnmp

Can you please suggest the way to get the mac addresses connected to remote subnet using python script.
Basically, let's say I am in a subnet and there is one more subnet in the organization, these two are connected via L3 switch which is of v2c type. For the subnet, I am in I can fetch MAC address  using arp table, but for the remote subnet(s) can you guide me the way using pysnmp / python script

Comment: Do you have the equipment's MIB

Comment: Yeah, I have it

Comment: Does your L3 tolerate this kind of operation

Comment: What is exactly the pb? have you alredy tried to do it

Comment: Yeah my L3 switch is capable of handling such load

Comment: Do you know how to work with MIBs and python

Comment: Yeah I have a fair idea on working with MIB and python m stuck here and that's why this question